# Android PHP : Can't Update data when using a not primary key in where clause in mysql query

Tags: php, android, mysql

Why I cant update a certain data in mysql database when I am using a non-primary key in where clause?, but when I use the primary key in the where clause it goes smoothly.

for some reason, I really need to use the non-primary key(instructor_id) in the where clause. Is there any problem in my code?

Here is the script:

```
<?php

$response = array();

if (isset($_POST['instructor_id']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {

    $uid = $_POST['instructor_id'];
    $password = md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']));

    require("DB_CONNECT1.php");

    $db = new DB_CONNECT();

    $result = mysql_query("UPDATE tb_user SET password = '$password' WHERE instructor_id = $instructor_id");

    if ($result) {

        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Password successfully updated.";

        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {

    }
} else {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    echo json_encode($response);
}

?>
```

and this is my mysql table:

[image]

Comment: You should really consider making instructor_id an integer.

Comment: Or, `WHERE instructor_id = '$instructor_id'"`

Comment: @Jeff But insturctor_id contains alphanumeric characters

Comment: @NanaPartykar Great!! It works now :) enclosing it with single quotes fix the problem hahaha thanks :)

Comment: Glad it worked @CallMeJeo. `:)` *Cheers*

Comment: you will get better performance by using an integer for instructor_id. Perhaps you need 1 more table like 'Instructors' with columns 'Instructor_id' and 'Instructor_code'.  Instructor_id would be a primary integer index while Instructor_code is your alphanumeric entry.  Just something for you to consider